# 現実に、社会のほうも、欠点のない何でも屋のような人間より、多少欠点はあっても、長所の抜きん出た人間のほうを重用するようになってきている。

Tags: meaning

> 現実に、社会のほうも、欠点のない何でも屋のような人間より、多少欠点はあっても、長所の抜きん出た人間のほうを重用するようになってきている。

Is 長所の抜きん出た人間のほう referring to

1 - 欠点のない何でも屋のような人間
or
2 - 多少欠点

Comment: `社会のほうも...` <-- Could you double-check it's 「[社会]{しゃかい}」(society) , and not 「[会社]{かいしゃ}」(company) ? (「重用する」だから...)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the basic structure of the sentence:

> 社会のほうも[=S]、AよりBのほうを[=O]重用するようになってきている[=V]。

Subject: 社会
Object: AよりBのほうを, B rather than A
Verb: 重用するようになってきている, has come to make much of; has started to appoint (person) to an important position

A = 欠点のない、「[何]{なん}でも[屋]{や}*」のような人間
B = 多少欠点はあっても、長所の[抜]{ぬ}きん[出]{で}た人間

*[何]{なん}でも[屋]{や} means [[何]{なに}をしてもひととおりできる人。](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E5%B1%8B/)